# Bash script to compare df -h free disk space to aria2c file size using sed

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I am trying to compare the output of `aria2c -S` with `df -h`.

For example `aria2c -S ../Radio* |grep 'Total Length'` gives:

`Total Length: 12GiB (13,191,069,983)`

and I want to compare with `df -H / | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}'` which gives:

`29G`

so something like this, but with the correct units. I guess regex with sed to isolate the numerals before `G` ?

```
#!/bin/bash
avail=$(df -H / | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}' | sed -r  's/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*/\1/')
filesize=$(aria2c -S ../file.zip |grep 'Total Length' | sed -r  's/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*/\1/')
if $avail < $filesize
echo "not enough free space"
else
aria2c $URL
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better if you compare the 2 numbers in bytes. so

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# get free disk space in KB 
avail_in_kb=$(df -BK / | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}' | sed -r  's/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*/\1/')

# get total size in bytes. \K for looking behind. (?=\)) for looking ahead. 
filesize_in_bytes=$(aria2c -S ../file.zip |grep -oP 'Total Length.*\(\K.*(?=\))'|tr -d ',')

# expression needs to be enclosed in brackets. -lt stands for less than. 
if [ "$((avail_in_kb*1024))" -lt "$filesize_in_bytes" ]
# keyword "then" is required. 
then
echo "not enough free space"
else
aria2c $URL
fi
```